# Rendering from another controller with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, model-view-controller

I have query to the db, where I ask for specific entries. This is the controller:

```
  def index

    @contributions = Contribution.all
    @number1 = params[:number1]
    @number2 = params[:number2]
    @itemsok = Contribution.where("first_item_id = ?",@number1).where("first_item_grade = ?",@number2) 


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @contributions }
    end
```

Ok and I have a form in the view wich allows me to pass data from the user input

```
<%= form_tag(contribution_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:number1, "First Item Id") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:number1) %>
  <%= label_tag(:number1, "First Item Grade") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:number2) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Do it!" , :remote => true) %>
<% end %>
```

That works perfectly, but now I want to render this function from the main page index (display_controller, display index.html.erb). I gave all the properties to the display_controller like this:

```
class DisplayController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = Item.all
    @contributions = Contribution.all
    @number1 = params[:number1]
    @number2 = params[:number2]
    @itemsok = Contribution.where("first_item_id = ?",@number1).where("first_item_grade = ?",@number2)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @contributions }
    end
  end

end
```

And I have the same form in the display view that is in the contributions view.... 
Right now what It does is that it redirects me to the contributions part, what I want t achive is to render the results in the display view...

Any thoughts? Thank you very much.
Sorry for my terrible english.

```
#
```

**I got it**

Got it the answer was to change in view the form to selected action

```
<%= form_tag(contribution_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:number1, "First Item Id") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:number1) %>
  <%= label_tag(:number1, "First Item Grade") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:number2) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Do it!" , :remote => true) %>
<% end %>
```

Change it to

```
<%= form_tag(display_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:number1, "First Item Id") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:number1) %>
  <%= label_tag(:number1, "First Item Grade") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:number2) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Do it!" , :remote => true) %>
<% end %>
```

In my case this was not working at the beginning but now I figured  that it was because I have my display_path as the root_path so I changed it to...

```
<%= form_tag(root_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:number1, "First Item Id") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:number1) %>
  <%= label_tag(:number1, "First Item Grade") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:number2) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Do it!" , :remote => true) %>
<% end %>
```

And now it works perfectly.

Can someone change this question to answered, I have like 21 of reputation and can't answer my own question. Tanks.

Comment: since you are using same form in for all the controller you can move it to a common partial view to reuse it. you need not repeat the code everytime. check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better code quelity you should avoid `repititions` of code and make reusable, move that formm to a common `partial view` and use `:url =>{:action => 'my_action'}` in the form tag then you can use it any `controller` `index` view. While form action it will take the `default` `controller` from which it will be rendered.

```
share/_form.erb.html

<%= form_tag(:url =>{:action => 'my_action'}, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:number1, "First Item Id") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:number1) %>
  <%= label_tag(:number1, "First Item Grade") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:number2) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Do it!" , :remote => true) %>
<% end %>
```

and in controller respective index view

```
 index.erb.html

 <%= render :partial 'share/form' %>
```

you can even declare variables for action and controller in your index method like

```
def index
 // do something
  @action = 'new_action'
  @controller = 'new_controller'
  // do some more thing
end
```

**and then in form**

```
:url =>{:controller => @controller, :action => @action}
```